# How to flip card and grow card but not scale content?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to create a feature where by a card flips on hover and then the card grows to fit the content, but the content does not. The page itself should also push down other content so there is no overlap.

I've managed to get the flip working but not the grow. Here is my code:

```
            <div class="card" id="first-card" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                <figure class="front"></figure>
                <figure class="back">
                    <div class="back-content">
                        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                        <hr>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce id lacus nisl. Vestibulum nec lectus at purus sodales ultricies. Quisque in ultrices leo. Nulla tempus pretium maximus. Proin non odio at enim scelerisque tempor eget at ligula. Cras at eros velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam in urna bibendum, posuere ligula sit amet, tincidunt magna.</p>
                    </div></figure>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
   .card .back {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
        transform: rotateY( 180deg);
        position: relative;
    }

    .card.flipped {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg) height 1s ease-in-out;
        transform: rotateY( 180deg) height 1s ease-in-out;
    }


    #first-card .front {
        background: url('card-img.jpg');
        z-index: 2;
    }

    #first-card .back {
        background: #fff;
    }
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.front', function (event) {
    $(this).parent().addClass('flipped');
    $(this).parent().addClass('expand');
}).on('mouseleave', '.card', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('flipped');
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You have syntax error in `.card.flipped`, we can't use `transform: rotateY( 180deg) height 1s ease-in-out;`, it's must be `transform: rotateY( 180deg); transition: height 1s ease-in-out;`

Comment: Thanks for spotting this, however it didn't solve the issue